# Quickly switch between fonts at runtime

Tags: key-bindings, gvim, font

While fonts can be manually selected in GVim from the menu, I have a few preferred fonts I would like to switch between depending on the task at hand *(small bitmap, larger OTF... etc)*.

Is there a way I can setup key-binding to cycle over a list of fonts predefined in my vimrc?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The basic idea could be something like:

```
" Define a list of the fonts you want to use, and the index in the 
" list of the default font. See :help Lists
let g:fc_list = [
\   "DejaVu Sans Mono 9",
\   "Source Code Pro 12",
\   "GohuFont 11"
\   ]
let g:fc_current = 0

" Set default font
let &guifont = g:fc_list[g:fc_current]

function! FontCycle()
  " Increment circular list. See :help expr-%
  let g:fc_current = (g:fc_current + 1) % len(g:fc_list)
  let &guifont = g:fc_list[g:fc_current]
endfunction

noremap <leader>fc :call FontCycle()<cr>
```

Answer (score 7):

I have the following defined in my .vimrc file.

```
set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ for\ Powerline\ 10
```

So you can set that up as a mapping like this...

```
nmap <Leader>f :set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ for\ Powerline\ 10<CR>
```

Add additional mappings for other fonts.