# Nvim black border issue

Tags: neovim, colorscheme, nvim

I am using nvim and color theme grubox and also I add the settings of my color theme.

at my vim editor has some black border at around left, right, top and bottom.

Anyone can help me to remove this black border as I attached?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Vim issue]

Comment: Is this a fullscreen terminal? You might want to read [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26321/19763).

Comment: Thank you, yes it is a fullscreen issue, I use that suggestion but no luck :(

Comment: I guess part of the black border is due to the terminal (maybe some type of border) and other parts are because VIm uses a fixed box to display characters. To quote the last sentence of the linked post: "It is still likely, that there is some small unused area to the left and bottom (see above). From my understanding this should be less than one char wide/high."